# How to make in TypeScript analogue of Java getClass() with generics?

Tags: javascript, java, typescript

I need to make analogue of Java `Object#getClass()` method with generics in TypeScript.

This is my Class class:

```
class Class<T> {

    public getName(): string {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

And I need to add to every Object `getClass(): Class<CLASS_NAME>` method. So I do:

```
declare global {

    interface Object {

        getClass(): Class<???>; //LINE X
    }
}
```

However, I can't understand what generics I should use at LINE X. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as far as types go, and the generic type of `Class` will get the type of the object it is invoked on :

```
class Class<T> {
    public constructor(private target: object) {}
    public getName(): string {
        return this.target.constructor.name;
    }
}

declare global {
    interface Object {
        getClass<T extends object>(this:T): Class<T>; 
    }
}

Object.prototype.getClass = function (this: object){
    return new Class(this);
}
class A {

}

console.log(new A().getClass().getName()) // A
```

**Note**: Please don't try to emulate Java in Typescript, this is usually a recipe for disaster. This while construct while possible in Typescript feels alien (adding fucntions to object, not usually a good idea for starters). If you have a concrete use case, post that and we can probably find a better solution.

Comment: Could you say how this construction `(this:T)` is called - I want to read about it.

Comment: @Jim2018 it's a type annotation for the this parameter, there isn't a lot of docs about it unfortunately.